# react-datepicker with no initial value

Tags: datepicker, reactjs

I started using the react-datepicker component.
https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker

I got the example running and now I want to adapt it that there is no initial value.
The example code is the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var container = document.querySelector('#datepicker-container');
 var exampleComponent = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'exampleComponent',
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
         start_date: moment(),
      };
    },
    handleStartDateChange: function(date) {
       this.setState({
          start_date: date
       });
    },
   render: function() {
      return React.DOM.div({}, [
         DatePicker({
         key: 'example1',
         selected: this.state.start_date,
         onChange: this.handleStartDateChange
      }),

      ]);
   }
})
React.renderComponent(exampleComponent(), container);
</script>
```

I tried to use `selected: none` or even leave `selected` out but then I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: newProps.date is null
     value: newProps.date.format(this.props.dateFormat)
```

I also looked into the source code, but didn't find any possibility to start with an empty date.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want by setting `start_date: null` in your `getInitialState`,

Alternatively, if you use example 3 from react-datepicker, you can define a function like this:

```
handleResetDate: function() {
    this.setState({
        new_date: null
    });
},
```

, and call it whenever you want the date to reset.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm using react-datepicker version 4.10

Setting `start_date` or `selected` to `null` didn't work for me, instead I simply changed the value for `selected` to `""`, as in `selected={""}`. That worked for me.